# ANTLR parsing works when using TestRig, but fails when parsing with Java

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have a grammar for evaluating csv files, and it works correctly according to TestRig. The following parse tree is generated:

[image]

If, however I use the following java code in my application, the parsing fails with an error:

```
line 2:33 no viable alternative at input '=A2+B2+C1'
```

Update: I'm now using the Char stream directly from file, but the error still remains.

```
 private static void parseFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        CSVLexer lexer = new CSVLexer(CharStreams.fromFileName("test.csv", StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTree tree = parser.start(); //start is the start rule
 }
```

It is my understanding that the TestRig does the same, so how can that succeed, and this fail?

Here is `test.csv` that im using to test:

```
12;=35.5+6*2;=A1+B1
"szoveg";"masik szoveg";=A2+B2+C1
```

As to how im calling the TestRig, im using the command line:

```
java -cp path\to\antln\jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig CSV start -gui
```

UPDATE: when using

```
java -cp path\to\antln\jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig CSV start -gui test.csv
```

I get the same error.

Comment: Can you show us your grammar, how you call the TestRig and what the contents of `fileContent` are? I'm assuming from the name that you're reading it from a file, correct? And presumably you ran the test rig on that same file, right? Can you show us the code you used for reading the file then? Note that you don't actually have to read a file into a string to parse it. You can create a `CharStream` from a file directly.

Comment: @sepp2k Added the information you requested, and I'm now using the antlr provided file reading (problem still remains).

Comment: So you're not running the TestRig on test.csv, you're entering the input manually? What happens when you run `java ... CSV start -gui test.csv`? And what are the contents of test.csv?

Comment: From what I remember you have to use an `ANTLRInputStream` to feed into the lexer. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Raven `ANTLRInputStream` is deprecated. `CharStreams.from...` is the preferred way to create `CharStream`s in current ANTLR versions.

Comment: @sepp2k When running test rig with the file, I get the same parsing error! Is it something with the file? I will include it into my question

Comment: @sepp2k I figured the problem out, see my answer. Thank you for pointing me the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my grammar requires a line break at the end of each line, and the `test.csv` DID NOT have a linebreak at the last line!

Upon hitting enter at the last line and saving, it now works.

**Solution:** To rewrite the line rule to make the last linebreak optional
**or** use java to add a linebreak at the end of the string read from file (I choose this)

```
if(!fileContent.endsWith("\n")) {
    fileContent += "\n";
}
```